# angular typescript Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Almost similar questions have been asked but relate to specific components such as gulp or webpack.

I am using VSCode and have installed the TypeScript libraries using TSD (I know it's deprecated but try finding any documentation on Typings and we'll talk again).

```
     /// <reference path="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
     /// <reference path="../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
     var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']);

     export interface IAppController {
        someFunc: (index:number) => void;
     }

     /*export*/ class AppController implements IAppController {
        static $inject = ["$scope", "$mdDialog"];    
        private $scope : any; 
        private $mdDialog : any;        
        constructor($scope, $mdDialog) {  
           this.$scope = $scope;     
           this.$mdDialog = $mdDialog;
        };    
        someFunc(index) {
              //...
           };
     }

     app.controller('appCtrl', AppController);
```

If the /*export*/ in front of the AppController class is not commented then the js produced from the ts will contain and fail on this line:

```
  exports.AppController = AppController;
```

with the error Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined.

Which brings the following questions:

- Why is this failing on the class but not the interface?
- Why export the controller class in the first place?
- Where is exports defined and what additional module should be installed?

Comment: exports is a nodejs service

Comment: what `module` option do you have in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @KhaledAwad: > exports is a nodejs service. The other modules are referenced in the html page so angular is defined when the page loads but node.js is not. So I think it is an issue with my test server configuration.

Comment: @Kutyel: only this: "module": "commonjs"